# Typesetting novel dialogue where one speaker has multiple paragraphs

Tags: environments, punctuation, paragraphs, quoting

I'm typesetting a novel wherein many characters have 2+ paragraphs of uninterrupted dialogue.

Example:

> “Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet…tik.
>
> “Nullam orci dolor, porttitor a…*julo?*
>
> “Nulla nibh nisl, fermentum id orci pulvinar, cursus varius eros.”

I have hitherto would typeset this passage like so:

```
``Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\dots tik.

``Nullam orci dolor, porttitor a\dots \emph{julo?}

``Nulla nibh nisl, fermentum id orci pulvinar, cursus varius eros.''
```

But I would like to know if the above format can be set with the csquote package or something similar, like:

```
\begin{SPEACH}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\dots tik. \par
Nullam orci dolor, porttitor a\dots \emph{julo?} \par
Nulla nibh nisl, fermentum id orci pulvinar, cursus varius eros.
\end{SPEACH}
```

My primary reason for asking this is because I use Sublime Text 2 for typesetting the novel and paragraphs that open with ``` `` ``` but don't close `''` messes up the syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution just declares a quotation style with `csquotes` and then creates a command `\speech{}` which uses that style. The group is necessary to limit the effect of the `everypar` style. The `everypar` style is based on the schema in `csquotes.cfg`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteStyle{everypar}% based on csquotes.cfg
  {\textquotedblleft}
  [\textquotedblleft]
  {\textquotedblright}
  {\textquoteleft}
  [\textquoteleft]
  {\textquoteright}
\newcommand\speech[1]{%
  \begingroup\setquotestyle{everypar}%
  \enquote{#1}\endgroup}

\begin{document}

\speech{%
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\dots tik. \par
  Nullam orci dolor, porttitor a\dots \emph{julo?} \par
  Nulla nibh nisl, fermentum id orci pulvinar, cursus varius eros.%
}

\end{document}
```

[image: speech]

Answer (score 2):

With this answer, I lap the left quotes to the beginning of the paragraph, but you could redefine ``` \def\andIquote{``} ``` if you wanted the traditional setting of quotes.

Likewise, I do not set aside extra vertical space, but that could be added with, for example, a `\medskip` at the beginning and end of the environment definition.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\def\andIquote{\makebox[0pt][r]{``}}
\let\svpar\par
\newenvironment{speech}
{\def\par{\svpar\andIquote}\andIquote\ignorespaces}{\unskip''\svpar}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{speech}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet\dots tik. \par
Nullam orci dolor, porttitor a\dots \emph{julo?} \par
Nulla nibh nisl, fermentum id orci pulvinar, cursus varius eros. 
\end{speech}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]